# Android accelerometer reading in any direction

Tags: java, android

I'm working on an android game, where the player's movement (left,top,right,bottom) is calculated depending on what direction you tilt your device.

I also wanted to do that at the beginning of the game, it calculates the current tilt, so that if the player is holding the phone in any position, he can still play the game.

Here is how I have done it:

(on start):

```
defaultAccelX = SceneManager.activity.getAccelX();
defaultAccelY = SceneManager.activity.getAccelY();
```

(and then on every update):

```
float modifiedAccelX = (SceneManager.activity.getAccelX() - defaultAccelX);
float modifiedAccelY = (SceneManager.activity.getAccelY() - defaultAccelY);
```

Now this works if the player keeps the phone towards the bottom. But if I hold the phone upside down, top and bottom are reversed, and right doesn't work.

Would anyone know how should I handle it to work in any direction ?

Thank you

Comment: "But if I hold the phone upside down, top and bottom are reversed, and right doesn't work." Does that mean that the right tilt moves the player to the left?

Comment: No the left tilts left, the right doesn't really move the player right, or slightly, a little bit weird.

Comment: if left works but right does not , why dont you try a roll from 11 o'clock to 3 o'clock in a full left turn .. and make logging of your coordinates .

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the linear acceleration sensors, Android provides access to the orientation sensors.

```
private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private Sensor mSensor;
...
mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
mSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION);
```

The orientation sensor can give you the azimuth (degree of rotation around the Z axis), pitch (same, but X axis), and roll (same, but Y axis).

The orientation sensor data can be accessed while your app is running, so that even if the orientation of the phone is changed during play you can figure out which way is up.

See the details at: [Android SDK: Position Sensors](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_position.html#sensors-pos-orient)